# Strange use of strlen

Tags: c++

I tried to compile the follow sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  if (strlen <= 0) {
    cout << "trace1" << endl;
    return 0;
  }
  cout << "trace2" << endl; 
  return 0;
}
```

The strange thing is that it compiles successfully. Do you have any idea why?

I have not declare the strlen as variable.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: test.cpp:8:7: error: 'strlen' was not declared in this scope

Comment: Did you write that yourself or find it somewhere? Also, that's not C

Comment: this code is C++. at least tag it appropriately.

Comment: @Kay: You cannot reproduce the error because `string.h` has not been included.

Comment: @Sriram: that probably reflects the interest of the person who wrote the code: to see whether `<string.h>` was being included by one of the other headers... it can vary between compilers/OSes etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do the same with other functions than `strlen`, this sample code will print trace2 because `strlen` is a pointer to function `size_t strlen ( const char * str )` and it's value should be a positive number.

```
cout << (size_t *) strlen << endl;
cout << (size_t *) strcat << endl;
```

for example the code above prints:

```
0x7fff84d29110
0x7fff84d63953
```

on my machine (as you see these are positive numbers because they are started with 7).

Also if I print `strlen` and `strcat` without casting to (size_t *) the result will be 1 which means that these functions are valid.

Comment: The pointers may happen to have "positive" values (for a signed type) on your system, but that's not guaranteed portable by the Standard - pointers tend to be unsigned anyway so `<= 0` is equivalent to `== 0`. Separately, if the function's weren't known, there'd be a compiler error rather than having a negative or NULL pointer, so the `if (strlen <= 0)` code can never be execute; makes the program pretty silly.

Comment: `that's not guaranteed portable by the Standard` doesn't make sense. Logically the memory addresses should be positive and the addresses ranges guarantees that they would be stored on a signed type without overflow.
If the function isn't declared there will be a compiler error but `(strlen == 1)` or `(strlen > 0)` means that the function is valid.

Comment: Logically, addresses aren't numbers, and so talking about positive or negative addresses makes no sense.  Formally, comparison of addresses for inequality (`<`, etc.) is only defined if the two addresses point into the same table; since you can't have tables of functions, using `<=` on a pointer to function is always undefined behavior.  A compiler could, and probably should warn about it, but it probably didn't occur to the authors of the compiler that anyone would actually try to do this.

Comment: @James: "using <= on a pointer to function is always undefined behavior" - except that I think `strlen <= strlen` is OK, guaranteed to be true, and pointless ;-)

Comment: @Steve Yes, as is the equally pointless `(void (*)())0 <= (void (*)())0`:-).  (And on checking, it's not undefined behavior, but simply an unspecified result.)

Answer (score 4):

Using just the identifier of a function decays to a function pointer of the corresponding type. In this case, `strlen` is a pointer of the type `size_t (*)(const char *)`. This pointer holds the address of the first instruction of the function in the executable code.

Testing the value of that pointer is legal, whatever the reason may be, although it seems strange in the code fragment you have provided.

Comment: it is legal, but the result of (strlen <= 0) is *unspecified*.

Comment: "This pointer holds the address of the first instruction of the function in the executable code." - not necessarily. For example if the function is thumb code on an ARM with interworking enabled, then the function pointer is 1 greater than the start of the function in memory.

Answer (score 3):

strlen without the () gives you a function pointer to the address where the strlen function is allocated in memory.

The program prints "trace1" if the library function strlen is allocated at an address less than 0, which is impossible on every computer in the world, or if it is allocated at address 0 (extremely unlikely but possible). Otherwise, if strlen is allocated at an address that is larger than zero (most likely the case), it prints "trace2".

Answer (score 2):

It's probably decays into an address which decays into an integer. A real compiler will probably fill the screen with warnings.

Comment: Exactly, you might want to revise your answer a little!